# How to develop a solid CSS strategy?

Tags: html, css, web-deployment

I have taken the time to carefully learn the syntax of HTML5, CSS3, and JQuery.

I would now like to find a good resource that will help me develop a solid "design process."  In what little design I've done up to this point, I've usually ended up with a pretty nasty looking .css style sheet with a lot of one-off-isms.

I'm open to any suggestions of a good resource or just some pointers that will help toward a good HTML/CSS design strategy.

Thanks

Comment: Basically create styles that you can use multiple times. Then add additional rules to objects you use less often. Use the 'cascading' effect to your advantage.

Comment: Strong, strong suggestion: [HTML and CSS Web Standards and Solutions, Christopher Murphy and Nicklas Persson](http://www.amazon.com/HTML-CSS-Standards-Solutions-Standardistas/dp/1430216069).  It addresses *precisely* the question you're asking.  It's also a great book.  IMHO...

Comment: paulsm4 - I just looked at the book on Amazon.  Do you think it is up-to-date enough?  It has a 2008 publishing date and speaks of XHTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break up your stylesheet into modules: Navigation, content types, header, footer, etc.

Don't use ids for assigning styles. This gives some more information on why that is, and more helpful tips http://oli.jp/2011/ids/

Read http://css-tricks.com/, Chris Coyier always has helpful tips on his site

Comment: ha!.. I literally just read that article a few hours ago.  Yea.  I think the guy is right, its best not to use ids for assigning styles.  Does everyone on here agree?

Comment: I will assign some styles to IDs - the float, the width, and padding (kind of like people used to treat table cells when table layouts was the only real viable option) - but now with the new HTML header, footer, and section tags, that's far less necessary. (Thank goodness.)

Comment: @user1763684 - No I don't agree. I think that the straw men he sets up in favour of using ids are irrelevant, and his one argument against them is bogus, born of a (widely held) misunderstanding that id and classes are part of CSS, when in fact what they are is semantic annotations of HTML markup. CSS Selectors form a binding between those semantics and the styling rules. The selector specificity rules exist for a reason, and are well chosen. Use them, don't fight them.

Answer (score 1):

Group your CSS styles, like @DevonRW said above.

Comment your CSS, just like you'd comment longer bits of code. It will help you and other team members in later maintenance.

Be careful, though, of doing something like creating a style definition that **just** defines the color of something. When using jQuery, you often end up needing to add classes, so that an element can have three or four classes at a given time...but you don't want to start out with three or four. Troubleshooting and making instant sweeping changes to your site styles can get really sticky that way.

One thing I've tried is coming up with a nomenclature for class names: sClassName for regular classes, jqClassName for classes that will be added (or removed) by jQuery. That may or may not be helpful to you, though.

Comment: I found a good resource today.  Lynda.com has a great course titled "CSS: Page Layouts" which is pretty helpful.